# Adding a subview to a UIButton with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout, subclass

I have created a subclass of `UIButton`. This subclass (`BubbleBtn`) is responsible for adding a `UIView` to the button.

The view that gets added should be 6 pts from the top, left, and right while spanning half the height of the parent button.

Code:

```
class BubbleBtn: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addBubbleView()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        addBubbleView()
    }
    func addBubbleView() {
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()
        let bubbleBuffer:CGFloat = 6
        let bubble = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: bubbleBuffer, y: bubbleBuffer, width: self.frame.width - (bubbleBuffer * 2), height: (self.frame.height / 2)))
        bubble.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        bubble.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
        bubble.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        bubble.layer.zPosition = -1
        self.addSubview(bubble)
    }
}
```

The problem is, the width and the height of the `UIView` that gets added is not the correct size; both the width and height fall to short on larger buttons.

How do I add the UIView to the buttons so that the bubble view renders in the proper size?

Screenshot posted below:

[image: Autolayout problem with subclass button]

Comment: add bubble.frame  = self.bounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding constraints for the view inside button.

```
func addBubbleView() {
   let bubble = UIView()
    bubble.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    bubble.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
    bubble.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    bubble.layer.zPosition = -1
    self.addSubview(bubble)
    bubble.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let views = [
        "bubble": bubble
    ]
    var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    let vBtnConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-6-[bubble]-6-|", options: .init(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    let hBtnConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-6-[bubble]-6-|", options: .init(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    constraints += vBtnConstraint
    constraints += hBtnConstraint
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of using VFL. The declaration of vBtnConstraint though, is there any way to make the vertical constraint a dynamic width of 'half' the button height?

Comment: I think you want the bubble to be centred with the height equal to half of the height of the button. Replace vBtnContraint with this: let vBtnConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-\(self.frame.height/4)-[bubble]-\(self.frame.height/4)-|", options: .init(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)

Comment: That crashed the app: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Oops..Add this: let vBtnConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-\\(self.frame.height/4)-[bubble]-\\(self.frame.height/4)-|", options: .init(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views) Missed out a slash in the before code

Comment: Aha! String interpolation in VFL. I modified your code a bit to: "V:|-6-[bubble]-\(self.frame.height/2)-|" - it somewhat works, however, the line 'self.frame.height/2' still isn't producing the correct value. i don't know if something is off in my constraints or auto layout. I just want the bubble to be half the height of the button, starting at 6 from the top, and ending at the halfway height of the btn. will keep at it

Comment: You can give the height of the bubble in brackets. Try this: let vBtnConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-6-[bubble(\\(self.frame.height/2))]", options: .init(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views) Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You should set frame by the `bounds` of the superview and the correct [`autoresizingMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622559-autoresizingmask).

```
let bubble = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: bubbleBuffer, y: bubbleBuffer,
    width: self.bounds.width - (bubbleBuffer * 2), 
    height: self.bounds.height - (2 * bubbleBuffer))
bubble.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
bubble.autoresizingMask = [ .flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight ]
```

So `bubble` adapts its width when the `frame` of the superview changes.